# Bootstrap navigation centering issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently having an issue while using Bootstrap and attempting to center it within my screen. I have the nav code wrapped in a container, I have display:flex and justify-content:center attached to them with no luck.

```
<div class="container nav-container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
      
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                >Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Twitter</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Facebook</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Instagram</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Town Page</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

```
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: margin : auto; on the nav can do it for you. By the way, your question says you want to center Bootstrap. I am assuming you want to center nav.

Comment: I apologize, correct I am looking to center the nav. Unfortunately, margin auto did not fix the issue.

Comment: If you want to center the content inside the nav, do what you have done to the nav-container to the nav. If you are trying to center the nav margin:auto should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I may have been targeting the wrong element within the CSS. Upon targeting `.navbar-nav` I was able to get the contents of the navigation bar centered within the bar itself.